# Pseudo selectors does not work when applying linear gradients

Tags: html, css

I am using simple pseudo-selector css functionlity. When I hover over my table-cells, they change background color, simple. But when the original background color of the table cells are  of linear gradient, the td:hover does not work anymore. Here is my code:

CSS:

```
#rightDiv td{
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px 5px;  
    /*background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);*/
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(55,160,252,1) 0%, rgba(8,126,216,1) 46%, rgba(28,97,175,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(55,160,252,1)), color-stop(46%,rgba(8,126,216,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(28,97,175,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(55,160,252,1) 0%,rgba(8,126,216,1) 46%,rgba(28,97,175,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(55,160,252,1) 0%,rgba(8,126,216,1) 46%,rgba(28,97,175,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(55,160,252,1) 0%,rgba(8,126,216,1) 46%,rgba(28,97,175,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(55,160,252,1) 0%,rgba(8,126,216,1) 46%,rgba(28,97,175,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#37a0fc', endColorstr='#1c61af',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
    border: 1px solid #444444;  
}

#rightDiv td:hover{
    color: #444444;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#rightDiv a{
    color: #fff;
}

#rightDiv a:hover{
    color: #444444;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="rightDiv">
    <table width="100%" height="100%">  
            <tr><td><a href="" target="_blank">Our Plans</a></td></tr>
            <tr><td><a href="" target="_blank">Our tariffs vs local mobile</a></td</tr>             
            <tr><td><a href="" target="_blank">Our service vs other VoIP</a></td></tr>          
            <tr><td><a href="" target="_blank">Our tariffs vs Skype</a></td></tr>                       
            <tr><td><a href="" target="_blank">Tariff lookup</a></td></tr>          
            <tr><td><a href="">Become an Agent/Franchisee</a></td></tr>           
    </table>
</div>
```

Any suggestions on why the linear gradient breaks my pseudo classes?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I set this up on JSFiddle, and it seems everything is working correctly as expected. http://jsfiddle.net/syjcE/

The only thing that I see is that you're setting the td:hover background color to white (background: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);). All I did was change the background color to an actual color so that you can see it's working.

Please let me know if I misunderstood the issue.

Comment: thanks, I solved the issue, in it is only in IE that it doesn't work. When I take away the opacity on the hover selector the problem goes away. But thanks, your answer helps.